# Plotting data against time in R

Tags: r, datetime, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame with one column as date/time(stored internally as numeric) and other columns as numeric/integer and I want to plot data against date/time.

Date/time in the data frame was populated using the following.

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S %p %m/%d/%Y',tz='GMT'))
```

`class(table$time)` is `numeric`.

1. How do I plot and show the data in x axis as readable date time in some format.
2. How do I plot subset of rows and not all rows Ex: rows between `dateTime1` and `dateTime2` where `dateTime1` and `dateTime2` are date given in a certain format.

Comment: Could it be possible for you to show what your dataframe looks like? I have trouble understand how your `time` can be both numeric and of the form '%H:%M:%S %p %m/%d/%Y' at the same time.

Answer (score 13):

You could also use `ggplot2`, more specifically `geom_point` or `geom_line` (note that I use the example data from @plannapus):

```
require(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw()) # Change the theme to my preference
ggplot(aes(x = time, y = variable), data = data) + geom_point()
```

[image]

or using a line geometry:

```
ggplot(aes(x = time, y = variable), data = data) + geom_line()
```

[image]

`ggplot2` automatically recognizes that the datatype of the x-axis is a date, and draws the axis accordingly.

Comment: +1 indeed way more convenient than mine. Is there also a way to control the format of the labels or their placement if needed?

Comment: Yes, you can use `scale_x_date` or `scale_x_datetime` to tweak the scales. See their documentation for some examples.

Answer (score 9):

Here is some dummy data:

```
data <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1338361200, 1338390000, 1338445800, 1338476400, 1338532200, 1338562800, 1338618600, 1338647400, 1338791400, 1338822000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), variable = c(168L, 193L, 193L, 201L, 206L, 200L, 218L, 205L, 211L, 230L)), .Names = c("time", "variable"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
data
              time variable
1  2012-05-30 09:00:00      168
2  2012-05-30 17:00:00      193
3  2012-05-31 08:30:00      193
4  2012-05-31 17:00:00      201
5  2012-06-01 08:30:00      206
6  2012-06-01 17:00:00      200
7  2012-06-02 08:30:00      218
8  2012-06-02 16:30:00      205
9  2012-06-04 08:30:00      211
10 2012-06-04 17:00:00      230
```

To show date and time in the axis you can use function `axis.POSIXct`:

```
plot(data, xaxt="n")
axis.POSIXct(side=1, at=cut(data$time, "days"), format="%m/%d")
```

You can control where the ticks fall with `at` (as for regular function`axis` except here it is to be provided with objects of class POSIXct) and control how they will appear with `format`.

As far as subsetting is concerned, as long as your dateTime1 and dateTime2 objects are also POSIXct objects you can do it as you would do any other kind of subsetting.

```
dateTime1 <- strptime("00:00 05/31/2012", format="%H:%M %m/%d/%Y")
dateTime2 <- strptime("3 Jun 2012 05-30", format="%d %b %Y %H-%M")
data[data$time < dateTime2 & data$time > dateTime1, ]
                 time variable
3 2012-05-31 08:30:00      193
4 2012-05-31 17:00:00      201
5 2012-06-01 08:30:00      206
6 2012-06-01 17:00:00      200
7 2012-06-02 08:30:00      218
8 2012-06-02 16:30:00      205
```