# Synchronise and plot two timeseries data sets in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I have two data sets from an experiment on a person during different ambient temperatures. **P1** represents a patient's physiological response data and **P1IAQ** represent the environmental monitoring data during the experiment. P1 recorded data 32 times per second but P1IAQ recorded data every 10 seconds.

```
head(P1IAQ)
     Time   RH  Temp CO2
1 12:04:07 44.2 19.89 664
2 12:04:17 44.2 19.89 664
3 12:04:27 44.2 19.89 665
4 12:04:37 44.2 19.89 665
5 12:04:47 44.2 19.89 666
6 12:04:57 44.2 19.89 668

head(P1)
      Time   SkinTemp HeartRate RespirationRate
1 00:00:00 27.781        70              10
2 00:00:00 27.780        70              10
3 00:00:00 27.779        70              10
4 00:00:00 27.779        70              10
5 00:00:00 27.778        70              10
6 00:00:00 27.777        70              10
```

The problem I have is that the time stamp on P1 is wrong. How can I plot them together on the same graph to see if the SkinTemp has a time-lag after the environmental temp is decreased?
[image: Skin Temp]
[image: Ambient Temp]

**EDIT: dput for P1IAQ**
I've added the first twenty values for the environmental data. I think the best thing would be to subtract 12:04:07 from all values to make the starting time 00:00:00. I've tried looking at lubridate.

```
library(lubridate)
P1IAQ$Time<-hms(P1IAQ$Time)
```

This datetime post looks interesting, but it's for plotting dates rather than actually altering them.
[Plotting data against time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146555/plotting-data-against-time-in-r)

```
dput(P1IAQ)
structure(list(Time = structure(1:19, .Label = c("12:04:07", 
"12:04:17", "12:04:27", "12:04:37", "12:04:47", "12:04:57", "12:05:07", 
"12:05:17", "12:05:27", "12:05:37", "12:05:47", "12:05:57", "12:06:07", 
"12:06:17", "12:06:27", "12:06:37", "12:06:47", "12:06:57", "12:07:07"
), class = "factor"), RH = c(44.2, 44.2, 44.2, 44.2, 44.2, 44.2, 
44.2, 44.2, 44.1, 44.1, 44.2, 44.2, 44.2, 44.3, 44.2, 44.2, 44.2, 
44.3, 44.3), Temp = c(19.89, 19.89, 19.89, 19.89, 19.89, 19.89, 
19.89, 19.89, 19.89, 19.89, 19.94, 19.89, 19.94, 19.94, 19.94, 
19.94, 19.94, 19.94, 19.94), CO2 = c(664L, 664L, 665L, 665L, 
666L, 668L, 668L, 669L, 667L, 670L, 670L, 672L, 675L, 677L, 682L, 
684L, 685L, 686L, 687L)), .Names = c("Time", "RH", "Temp", "CO2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

**EDIT: I've synchronised the times using lubridate:**

```
P1IAQ$Time<-period_to_seconds(hms(as.character(P1IAQ$Time))-hms("12:04:07"))
P1$Time<-period_to_seconds(hms(as.character(P1$Time)))
```

But now plotting them together is tricky. I've tried ggplot2 but I can't get two vertical axes. Any thoughts

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = P1IAQ, aes(x = Time, y = Temp, color = "red")) +
  geom_line(data = P1, aes(x = Time, y = Temp, color = "blue"))  +
  xlab('Time (s)') +
  ylab('Temperature ºC')
```

[image]

Comment: When you say the timestamp `P1` is wrong, do you mean that there's a constant offset from the true time? If so, what is the offset?

Comment: @eipi10 I would like to move the start time of the environmental monitoring time from 12:04:07 to  0:0:0 to coincide with the skin temperature's time. (or vice versa).

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean with your statement "the timestamp on `P1` is wrong". Thanks.

Comment: @lrnzcig the times of the experiment should either both start at 0:0:0 or 12:04:07. Basically the clock wasn't set to the correct time on P1.

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to see what the time-lag is between a change in Ambient temp (P1IAQ) and the response from skin temp (P1).

Comment: Ok, understood. I don't know what's the type of your data, but you could use e.g. the `chron` package to convert your times, and then you can directly subtract/add a fixed amount of time, e.g. you could add a chron type of 12:04:07 to the times in `P1`. If you cannot make it work, please edit your question and add the types so that it can be answered easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the times in each data frame to be on a common scale, you can convert both of them to numeric seconds elapsed since the start of the experiment and not worry about date or time classes. Then you can join the two data frames based on the common time scale.

I used your `P1IAQ` data sample and created fake `P1` data to go with it. `Time` in my `P1` is probably not in the same format as your actual data. If you post a sample of your `P1`, I can adjust the example below to fit your actual data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(hms)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_light())

# Fake P1 data frame
set.seed(10)
n=32*60*3 + 1
P1 = data.frame(Time=as.POSIXct(seq(0,180,length.out=n), origin=as.Date("2016-05-01"), tz="GMT"),
                SkinTemp = round(cumsum(rnorm(n, 0, 0.01)) + 27.78, 2),
                RespirationRate=round(rnorm(n, 10, 0.5)))
```

Convert `P1$Time` and `P1IAQ$Time` to numeric values equal to the number of seconds elapsed since the start of the experiment. (Note that `P1IAQ$Time` in the data you posted is a `factor`, so I converted to character before further processing.):

```
P1$nTime = as.numeric(as.hms(P1$Time))

P1IAQ$nTime = as.numeric(as.hms(as.character(P1IAQ$Time)))
P1IAQ$nTime = P1IAQ$nTime - min(P1IAQ$nTime)
```

Join `P1` and `P1IAQ` by `nTime`:

```
P1j = full_join(P1, P1IAQ, by="nTime", suffix=c("_P1","_P1IAQ")) %>%
  # Make sure joined data frame is sorted by nTime
  arrange(nTime) %>% 
  # Fill missing values with Last One Carried Forward
  mutate_at(vars(Time_P1IAQ, RH, Temp, CO2), na.locf)
```

Plot after converting data from wide to long format:

```
ggplot(P1j %>% select(Time_P1IAQ, nTime, Skin=SkinTemp, Ambient=Temp) %>%
         # Convert from wide to long format for plotting
         melt(id.var=c("Time_P1IAQ", "nTime")), 
       aes(nTime, value, group=Time_P1IAQ)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales="free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.5,0)) +
  labs(x="Elapsed Time (sec)", y=expression(Temperature~"("*degree*C*")"))
```

[image]

Another option is to plot temperature changes relative to the start of the experiment. That way, you can have both lines on the same panel without having to deal with them being in different locations:

```
ggplot(P1j %>% select(Time_P1IAQ, nTime, Skin=SkinTemp, Ambient=Temp) %>% 
         # Convert from wide to long format for plotting
         melt(id.var=c("Time_P1IAQ", "nTime")) %>% 
         # Convert temperatures to difference from starting values
         group_by(variable) %>% 
         mutate(value = value - value[nTime==min(nTime)]), 
       aes(nTime, value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Elapsed Time (sec)", y=expression(Temperature~Change~"("*degree*C*")"),
       colour="")
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! I'm wondering if there's a way of finding out what the time-lapse is before a shift in environmental temperature affects skin temperature. Do you think it's best to do it visually from the graph? Or numerically? But I'm not sure signal processing is the right way forward...

Comment: I've plotted all the variables in the format of your first graphs. Do you know how to make the titles of the y axes all different? E.g. Temperature, CO2(ppm), etc.

Comment: For your first question, I suggest asking a question on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), a Q&A site for statistical advice. One thing you might was to consider is whether is makes sense to interpolate the `P1IAQ` values rather than assume they are flat in between measurements. Interpolation seems like a good option if you have reason to believe the values change monotonically between measurements.

Comment: For your second question, if you're plotting different types of measurements in each panel, I think you'd need to create separate graphs and then lay them out together (using `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package or `plot_grid` from the `cowplot` package).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your data but i will prepare something similar... In this case the length of P1 is diferent with P1IAQ:

```
library(ggplot2)
#I create a sample of your data
P1<-data.frame(1:10,51:60)
P1IAQ<-data.frame(1:8,1:8)
colnames(P1)<-c("Time","Temp")
colnames(P1IAQ)<-c("Time","Temp")

# I cathegory your data for plot
df = data.frame(Time=c(P1$Time,P1IAQ$Time), values=c(P1$Temp,P1IAQ$Temp),type=c(rep("P1",length(P1$Time)),rep("P1IAQ",length(P1IAQ$Time))))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Time, y=values, color=type)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(type ~ ., scales="free") +
  xlab('Time (s)') +
  ylab('Temperature ºC')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. One thing that stands out is that my columns of P1IAQ$Temp and P1$Temp are very different lengths...

Comment: New Update with your requeriments!